# about indirect addressing like %segreg:disp(base,index,scale),foo

Tags: gcc, disassembly, addressing

movl   $0x14,0x4(%rax,%rdx,1)
meas %rax+%rdx*1+0x4 = $0x14（20）

but：
mov    0x0(,%rax,8),%rax
which is base segment resgister ？
what is this instuction meas？

Answer (score 1):

Load into `%rax` the value from memory at the address `%rax * 8`. No base register and no offset just means those parts of the `base + index * multiplier + offset` are assumed to be `0x0`.